# I cannot access a partition in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, users

I am running ubuntu version 14.04 and I have two user accounts. After logging into the standard account and accessing one of my disk partitions, I tried to get into my admin account but I cannot access the same partition after clicking on the files manager on the launcher. What could be the solution?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “New Volume”.

Comment: the above is stated in a dialogue box

Comment: after accessing a partition in the account with limited priviledges, i couldnot access the same partition in the main account that has all the priviledges

Comment: How are you trying to access the partition? Could you please [edit] your question when you want to clarify or add something? Thanks.

Comment: clicking on the files manager on the launcher

Comment: What's the output of `id`, `ls -ld <MOUNTPOINT>`, and `grep -Fe <MOUNTPOINT> /proc/mounts` where `<MOUNTPOINT>` is the path where the file system on that partition is "mounted"? What's the output of `udisksctl --info --block-device <DEVICE>` where `<DEVICE>` is the path to the device node of the partition? You can find an overview of all available block devices and their mountpoints in the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   161G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   150G  0 part /media/b/New Volume1
├─sda5   8:5    0    20G  0 part /media/b/New Volume
├─sda6   8:6    0   5.5G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0 128.9G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.